# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object 3.6.1

Tags: plugin-development

I am using function query() and get_results in my plugin code but, it gives me this 
error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object".
I have this lines of code:

```
class Dynamic_form {

    function product_category(){
        global $wpdb;
        $TablePressData = $wpdb->query(
                "
                    SELECT post_title
                    FROM $wpdb->posts
                    WHERE post_type = 'tablepress_table'
                "
            );
        return print_r($TablePressData);
    }
}
```

I am using version 3.6.1 (My client already using the version so I'm afraid of updating it).

Comment: Where/when do you call this function?

Comment: In the index file of my plugin; plugin/myfolder/index.php.

Comment: actually this is already solved. I add this function.

if(!class_exists("RGForms")){
     for ( $i = 0; $i < $depth = 10; $i++ ) {
         $wp_root_path = str_repeat( '../', $i );

         if ( file_exists("{$wp_root_path}wp-load.php" ) ) {
             require_once("{$wp_root_path}wp-load.php");
             require_once("{$wp_root_path}wp-admin/includes/admin.php");
             break;
         }
     }

     //redirect to the login page if user is not authenticated
     auth_redirect();
 }

Comment: Your issue is clear now - you can't load plugin or template files directly because the WordPress environment is not loaded. You should use a [rewrite endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) to allow direct access to your plugin rather than requiring `wp-load.php`, which will make your code less portable. Any plugin which does that would be rejected from the WordPress.org plugin repository.